# How to compare returned binary values with date using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, compare

I am running an sql query which returns me a column `days` which consist of the following like value `1111100` . Here each bit represent each day for example say first bit `'1'` in the returned value is Monday and the sixth bit `'0'` is Saturday. Now I want to perform some action based on these returned values. For example say If Monday is `'1'` I want to trigger one action on Monday and if Monday is `'0'` I don't have to perform any action on Monday. What method can be used in NodeJs to achieve this requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Jobs
let monJob = () => { console.log('Monday') };
let tueJob = () => { console.log('Tuesday') };
let wedJob = () => { console.log('Wednesday') };
let thuJob = () => { console.log('Thursday') };
let friJob = () => { console.log('Friday') };
let satJob = () => { console.log('Saturday') };
let sunJob = () => { console.log('Sunday') };

// Inputs
let bitDays = '0111100';
//let days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

// Verify block
let jobs = [monJob, tueJob, wedJob, thuJob, friJob, satJob, sunJob]
bitDays.split('').forEach((bit, index) => {
    if (bit == '1')
        jobs[index]();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is function for this in Node.js, but you can do:

```js
const mask = "1111100";
const dayOfWeekMap = [
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
  "Sunday",
];

for (let idx in mask) {
  if (mask[idx] === "1") {
    console.log(`Do something on ${dayOfWeekMap[idx]}`);
  }
}
```